# mongodb create an index and convert string to number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am wanting to create an index E.G.

```
   db.collection.createIndex({"new_id":1})
```

The issue is that **new_id** is a string, and it is getting sorted as a string even though I am wanting it be treated as a number such as "123456" to 123456. Is there anyway to convert it to a number while creating the index?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not changing the way new_id is stored from string to int to begin with?

Comment: Hi, there are already a large amount of documents that are like this. I was thinking that as new_id is always a string, the index should work as well as if it was a number?

Comment: String sort won't work as Int sort does. I would recommend changing the existing document types from String to Int ( one possible method is .forEach() ). How many documents currently exist?